# register method missing in faulthandler

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I'm getting the following error message while trying to kick off iPython's notebook:

```
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 326, in patch_io
    faulthandler_register = faulthandler.register
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'register'
```

This is under Python 3.4.  Looking in Python documentation I see that [register is a documented method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/faulthandler.html#faulthandler.register):

> faulthandler.register(signum, file=sys.stderr, all_threads=True,
>   chain=False)
>
> > Register a user signal: install a handler for the
> >     signum signal to dump the traceback of all threads, or of the current
> >     thread if all_threads is False, into file. Call the previous handler
> >     if chain is True.

However looking into the faulthandler module, I don't see the method listed:

```
C:\>\Python34\python.exe
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import faulthandler
>>> dir(faulthandler)
['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 
'_fatal_error', '_read_null', '_sigabrt', '_sigfpe', '_sigill', '_sigsegv', 
'cancel_dump_traceback_later', 'disable', 'dump_traceback', 
'dump_traceback_later', 'enable', 'is_enabled']
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You might have packages out of date, try `pip install --upgrade jupyter ipython`.

Comment: they are brand new installs.  But regardless, I did check versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue (python 3.5-64, windows, fully updated), you can upgrade ipykernel to an newer version (`>=4.3.1`) version where this is  resolved :

`pip install ipykernel --upgrade`

You can also downgrade it (to `<4.3`) but downgraded is not recommended.

There is a bug in ipykernel 4.3.0. which was introduced during the 4.2.x cycle and affect only windows users.

An issue has been filled [on GitHub](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/107), which will be fixed in 4.3.1 which has now been released.

Comment: And it looks like the update is out and is solving this issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you read a bit further down in the documentation you quoted, you'll see the reason `register` is not available for you:

> Not available on Windows.

Comment: Oh, crap... Good catch!  Interesting, so this means that iPython's Notebook server doesn't work under Windows. I didn't see any statements to this fact.

Comment: It's not deliberate. There will be a new release of ipykernel (4.3.1) very soon to fix that.